# Undefining a method or alternative

Tags: php, oop, methods

With this plugin system, there is a Utility and a Driver.  The driver extends the utility, however, some drivers support different functions than others, some don't support certain functions.

My class would be something of the sort:

```
Class Utility {

  public function MethodOne() {
    # default MethodOne
  }

  public function MethodTwo() {
    # default MethodTwo
  }

}

class Driver extends Utility {
  # MethodTwo not supported in this driver
}
```

The easy thing about undefining a method would be it would allow the developer using the class to run a method_exists call to see if the driver supports the method.

Is it possible to undefine a method in an extended class or is there a good alternative?

Comment: Why don't you only include the common methods in utility and let every driver define his own extra methods? What's the point of inheritance in your case.

Comment: @amrhady: That wouldn't allow for changes later on.  If someone adds a new driver that doesn't support a function, then you have to go back and possibly alter every other class.

Comment: But that's exactly my point. This is the opposite of inheritance and you are using inheritance to solve it.

Comment: The inheritance is because most of the functions are shared between the drivers.  But some drivers, especially new drivers, don't have all the functionality built in (yet).   So if someone wants to use a new driver that doesn't have a function supported yet (or maybe ever), they would either need to define all the common functions in that class and not extend the Utility or they would need to go back and remove the function not supported from the Utility and then add the function in every single Driver that does support it.  Even way it limits the ease of adding new drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object orientated languages, you usually cannot change the visibility of
a method if not for widen it.

But while PHP does not support restricting the visibility of a method with the classical inheritance, it turns out it allows it when it comes to traits.

```
<?php

trait Utility {
    public function methodOne() {

    }
    public function methodTwo() {

    }
}

class Driver {
    use Utility;
    protected function methodTwo(){

    }
}
```

And here we go:

```
php > $driver = new Driver;
php > $driver->methodTwo();

PHP Fatal error:  Call to protected method Driver::methodTwo() from context '' in php shell code on line 1
```

**Warning:**

`method_exists` will return true no matter what the visibility is. You have to use `is_callable`:

```
php > var_dump(is_callable([$driver, 'methodOne']));
bool(true)
php > var_dump(is_callable([$driver, 'methodTwo']));
bool(false)
```

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you!  That looks great, is_callable is probably better than method_exists anyways.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't undefine a parent function within a child, and it's not a great way to use inheritance. Any child class should be able to use all the parent functions. (Otherwise, why bother extending?)

Another solution is to just define the functions you need in each specific driver while Utility just contains common functions (which is the easiest) that all drivers would be able to use, and then driver specific functions inside the drivers.

```
Class Utility {

    public function MethodOne() {
        # default MethodOne
    }

    public function MethodTwo() {
        # default MethodTwo
    }

}

class Driver extends Utility {
    public function MethodThree() {

    }
}

class Driver2 extends Utility {
    public function MethodFour() {

    }
}
```

This shows that Driver and Driver2 have different implemented functions than each other while still both having the methods available in Utility.

A final solution (if you wanted to force functions to be in the drivers otherwise throw an error) would be to implement multiple interfaces each bundling some number of functions together:

```
Class Utility {

    public function MethodOne() {
        print "MethodOne";
    }

    public function MethodTwo() {
        print "MethodTwo";
    }

}

interface inter1 {
    public function MethodThree();
}

interface inter2 {
    public function MethodFour();
}

class Driver extends Utility implements inter1 {
    public function MethodThree(){
        print "MethodThree";
    }    
}

class Driver2 extends Utility implements inter2 {
    public function MethodFour() {
        print "MethodFour";
    }
}
```

Both solutions achieve the same thing, but Driver has to implement MethodThree in the interface solution:

```
$d = new Driver();
print "Methods for Driver:\n";
foreach (array("MethodOne","MethodTwo","MethodThree","MethodFour") as $k) {
    $p = method_exists($d, $k) ? 'true' : 'false';
    print "\t ".$k.": " . $p ."\n";
}

$d = new Driver2();
print "Methods for Driver2:\n";
foreach (array("MethodOne","MethodTwo","MethodThree","MethodFour") as $k) {
    $p = method_exists($d, $k) ? 'true' : 'false';
    print "\t ".$k.": " . $p ."\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Methods for Driver:
    MethodOne: true
     MethodTwo: true
     MethodThree: true
     MethodFour: false
Methods for Driver2:
    MethodOne: true
     MethodTwo: true
     MethodThree: false
     MethodFour: true
```

If you wanted Driver2 to have MethodThree, then you would write:

```
class Driver2 extends Utility implements inter2, inter1 {
    public function MethodFour() {
        print "MethodFour";
    }

    public function MethodThree() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your write up.  Interfaces like that could get messy as we're talking about up to 100 functions in a class and not knowing what function is supported by all drivers especially considering new drivers can be added a later date that may not support a function.  So in that case, I would have to go back and edit every single other class for compatibility. (Removing the function from Utility and adding the interface to every other Driver)

Comment: It feels like the best you're going to get is override parent functions with something that throws a BadMethodCallException and then there's a array $not_implemented part of Utility that gets overwritten by each driver that then you'd add all functions not done yet, and have a function get_defined_functions() { return method_exists($this, "method") && !in_array("method", $not_implemented); }

Comment: Yes, it looks that way.  I'll give you an upvote because your answer may help others who come across this question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?php

class Utility{

    //will hold unimplemented methods foor every child
    protected $unimplementedMethods = array();

    protected function f1(){

        //debug
        echo __FUNCTION__ . "\n";
    }

    protected function f2(){

        //debug
        echo __FUNCTION__ . "\n";
    }

    //intercept the functions
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (method_exists($this,$name) && !in_array($name, $this->unimplementedMethods)){
            echo "Calling method: '$name'\n";
            $this->$name();
        }
        else{
            //return error or throw exception
            echo "Method: '$name' is not implemented for this driver\n";
        }
    }
}

//driver1
class Driver1 extends Utility{

    //set your non-implemented methods
    protected $unimplementedMethods = array ('f2');

}

//driver2
class Driver2 extends Utility{

    //set your non-implemented methods
    protected $unimplementedMethods = array ('f1');
}

//init
$d1 = new Driver1();
$d2 = new Driver2();


$d1->f1(); //the ok method
$d1->f2(); //the nok method


$d2->f1(); //the nok method
$d2->f2(); //the ok method  
?>
```

Output:

```
Calling method: 'f1'
Method: 'f2' is not implemented for this driver
Method: 'f1' is not implemented for this driver
Calling method: 'f2'
```

Comment: Looks like a good alternative +1.  You could incorporate an exception in the __call() like MasterOdin had suggested.  Doesn't work with method_exists but that seems to not be possible.